# Capture many .png files over HTTP that are named as .htm?

Tags: http, png, mime-types, capture

I want to download a large number of .png files that have .htm file extensions. I've tried a some WinPcap-based utilities, but none of them pick up the files I need. The utilities I have tried are called York, EtherWatch and Pikachu2. I've also tried using a Firefox extension called Save Images - which was too buggy to be useful - and I've tried looking in the browser cache. This last approach works, but it has a problem...

...I need at least the last 30 characters of the file names to be maintained so that I know which image is which.

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [downthemall](http://www.downthemall.net/) to download all the images, and rename the file extension programmatically

Comment: Downloadthem all doesn't work for this. I can manually tell it to get all the right files, but they all fail to download. I can get the files by typing their URLs, but I don't have all the URLs.